# Skip div within div simple html dom

Tags: dom, simple-html-dom

A page that I want to scrape data from has the following elements

```
<div class="content">
 <p>I want this</p>
 <p>I want this</p>
 <div class="row">
   <p>I do not want this</p>
   <p>I do not want this</p>

 </div>
</div>
```

I do not want paragraphs in the `<div class="row">`
This is what I have tried so far. Doesnt seem to work

```
foreach ($sample_html->find('div[class=entry-content]') as $content) {

                foreach($content->find('div[class=row]') as $row){

                    foreach ($row->find('p') as $skip) {

                        $skip->outertext = '';
                    }
                }

                foreach($content->find('p') as $paragraph){

                    //echo $paragraph;
                    $paragraphs .= '<p>'.$paragraph->innertext.'</p>';
                    echo $paragraphs;
                }


            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 $skip->outertext = '';
```

to

```
 $skip->innertext= '';
```